# R style categorical descriptive statistics in python

Tags: python, r

In python `pandas.describe(includes='all'),` the categorical attributes only show "count, unique, top, and freq" where you do not know the "null, counts of categorical values". For example, I have a 'sex' variable where it does not show how many male/female are there or NAs. But in R, a `summary()` would do the jobs for both numbers or categorical variables.
How can you achieve a R style `summary()` in python. BTW, the output of `includes='all'` option is not quite user friendly compared to R

[image: Python]
[image: R output]

Comment: Use `df['Sex'].value_counts()` as a quick and dirty substitute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider creating a user-defined summary list one for numeric and other for categorical (i.e., *object* types) columns to replicate R's summary output. Even remove the `if` in list comprehension to return counts for all columns. Below uses Titanic dataset from @vincentarelbundock'S [R datasets page](https://vincentarelbundock.github.io/Rdatasets/datasets.html):

```
df = pd.read_csv('https://vincentarelbundock.github.io/Rdatasets/csv/datasets/Titanic.csv', 
                 index_col=0)

summary_list = [df.describe()] + \
               [df.groupby([c])[df.columns[0]].count() \
                for c in df.columns if df[c].dtype == 'object']

for i in summary_list:
    print(i)
    print()
```

**Output**

```
              Age     Survived      SexCode
count  756.000000  1313.000000  1313.000000
mean    30.397989     0.342727     0.351866
std     14.259049     0.474802     0.477734
min      0.170000     0.000000     0.000000
25%     21.000000     0.000000     0.000000
50%     28.000000     0.000000     0.000000
75%     39.000000     1.000000     1.000000
max     71.000000     1.000000     1.000000

Name
Abbing, Mr Anthony                               1
Abbott, Master Eugene Joseph                     1
Abbott, Mr Rossmore Edward                       1
Abbott, Mrs Stanton (Rosa)                       1
Abelseth, Miss Anna Karen                        1
Abelseth, Mr Olaus                               1
Abelson, Mr Samuel                               1
Abelson, Mrs Samuel (Anna)                       1
Abraham, Mrs Joseph (Sophie Easu)                1
Abrahamsson, Mr August                           1
Adahl, Mr Mauritz Nils Martin                    1
Adams, Mr John                                   1
Ahlin, Mrs Johanna Persdotter                    1
Ahmed, Mr Ali                                    1
Aijo-Nirva, Mr Isak                              1
Aks, Master Philip                               1
Aks, Mrs Sam (Leah Rosen)                        1
Aldworth, Mr Charles Augustus                    1
Alexander, Mr William                            1
Alhomaki, Mr Ilmari Rudolf                       1
Ali, Mr William                                  1
Allen, Miss Elisabeth Walton                     1
Allen, Mr William Henry                          1
Allison, Master Hudson Trevor                    1
Allison, Miss Helen Loraine                      1
Allison, Mr Hudson Joshua Creighton              1
Allison, Mrs Hudson JC (Bessie Waldo Daniels)    1
Allum, Mr Owen George                            1
Andersen, Mr Albert Karvin                       1
Andersen, Mr Thor Olsvigen                       1
                                                ..
Williams, Mr Charles Duane                       1
Williams, Mr Charles Eugene                      1
Williams, Mr Fletcher Lambert                    1
Williams, Mr Howard Hugh                         1
Williams, Mr Leslie                              1
Williams, Mr Richard Norris II                   1
Wilson, Ms Helen                                 1
Windelov, Mr Einar                               1
Wirz, Mr Albert                                  1
Wiseman, Mr Phillippe                            1
Wittevrongel, Mr Camiel                          1
Woolner, Mr Hugh                                 1
Wright, Miss Marion                              1
Wright, Mr George                                1
Yalsevac, Mr Ivan                                1
Yasbeck, Mr Antoni                               1
Yasbeck, Mrs Antoni                              1
Young, Miss Marie Grice                          1
Youssef, Mr Gerios                               1
Yrois, Miss Henriette                            1
Zabour, Miss Hileni                              1
Zabour, Miss Tamini                              1
Zakarian, Mr Artun                               1
Zakarian, Mr Maprieder                           1
Zenni, Mr Philip                                 1
Zimmerman, Leo                                   1
de Brito, Mr Jose Joaquim                        1
de Villiers, Madame Berthe                       1
del Carlo, Mr Sebastiano                         1
del Carlo, Mrs Sebastiano (Argenia Genovese)     1
Name: Name, dtype: int64

PClass
*        1
1st    322
2nd    279
3rd    711
Name: Name, dtype: int64

Sex
female    462
male      851
Name: Name, dtype: int64
```